# How do I access Assembly Attributes in a Universal Windows App?

Tags: c#, attributes, uwp

I'm trying to get the values from some of my assembly's attributes, for example the various version attributes plus some custom attributes.

When I try to access `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` it's gone! `System.Reflection.Assembly` seems to have only one method, `Load()`.

So how do I access my attribute values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know in WinRT to retrieve the assembly is through the `GetTypeInfo` extension method. It's defined in the namespace `System.Reflection`:

```
using System.Reflection;

...

        foreach (var attribute in this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.CustomAttributes)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(attribute);
        }
```