# Equivalent of system.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName

Tags: windows, silverlight, uwp

At the moment I am porting an Windows phone Silverlight application to windows mobile using the UWP Platform.

In my old code I used a function to get the ExecutingAssemblyName in the following way:

```
        public static string ExecutingAssemblyName {
        get {
            string name = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
            return name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf(','));
        }
    }
```

now I want to get the same result in Windows mobile but the functions described in the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) do not all seem to be there in Windows mobile.. The only ones I can find are :

1. System.Reflection.Assembly.equals
2. System.Reflection.Assembly.load
3. System.Reflection.Assembly.ReferenceEquals

Does anybody now how to get the same result? Or should I start rewriting a lot of code.

Thank you already

Comment: If this requires rewriting "a lot of code" then you are doing something very, very wrong.  Reflection is pretty iffy in UWP apps, .NET Native is going to give you no end of grief.  You must describe why you need this to get a usable answer.

Comment: If you need AssemblyName, then [following Kookiz answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33592586/2681948), maybe you can use `this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName`. Nevertheless I would follow Hans Passant's advice.

Comment: i use the assemblyname to return it with functions in my Resourceheper class. Whenever i want to get something, a stream for an example i do it in the following way using the ExecutingAssemblyName.

    public static Stream GetStream(string relativeUri) {
            return GetStream(relativeUri, ExecutingAssemblyName);
        }

That's why i need it and i have no idea how to get the assembly name right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the full name of an assembly, you can use the code as following (as Romasz mentioned).

```
this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName
```

In UWP, all of the app submitted to the store will be complied with .NET Native.

> The .NET Native runtime doesn't include a JIT compiler. As a result,
>   all necessary native code must be generated in advance. A set of
>   heuristics is used to determine what code should be generated, but
>   these heuristics cannot cover all possible metaprogramming scenarios.

For more information, please refer the article [Reflection and .NET Native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600640(v=vs.110).aspx).

In your case, I suggest you using the resource file (Resources.resw) to manage the text resource and put the file resources (like images, icons) under the Assets folder.

[image]

Comment: Might be better for me to look into this. Thanks for the advice might take a little longer but seems like the best solution.